# Return the cube of a number in Python

Tags: python

stuck on this exercise.

INSTRUCTIONS

> First, def a function called `cube` that takes an argument called
>   `number`. Don't forget the parentheses and the colon!
>
> Make that function return the cube of that number (i.e. that number
>   multiplied by itself and multiplied by itself once again).
>
> Define a second function called `by_three` that takes an argument called
>   `number`. if that number is divisible by 3, `by_three` should call
>   `cube(number)` and return its result. Otherwise, `by_three` should return
>   `False`.

MY CODE

```
def cube(number): 
    return number ** number ** number 

def by_three(number)
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Your cube function is x^x^x, not x•x•x, change it

Answer (score 6):

`number ** number ** number` isn't the cube of `number`, rather it is the 3rd [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of number.

In your cube function, you could use `math.pow` if you're going to need other math functions or simply `number ** 3`:

```
import math 

def cube(number): 
    return math.pow(number, 3) # number ** 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def cube(number): 
    return number * number * number
```

x ** y means x ^y (x raised to the power y).

Answer (score 1):

`**` is not the multiplication operator, it's the power operator. Your `cube` function actually returns x<sup>x<sup>x</sup></sup>, not xxx. You should use the `*` (multiplication) operator instead:

```
def cube(number): 
    return number * number * number 
    # Here -------^--------^
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and it worked:

```
def cube(number):
    return number*number*number

def by_three(number):
    if number%3==0:
          return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```